# Remix & Metamask: displaying more than one account

Tags: remix, metamask

I'd like to test a contract on Remix and since it uses Oraclize, I can't use the javascript VM. So I'm connecting to Ropsten by selecting Injected web3 as environment on Remix.

The problem is that I need to make more than 1 account available for testing, but Remix will only load the currently selected account on Metamask.

Is there a way to access more accounts so de dropdown box allows me to switch between them?

I already tried switching accounts on Metamask but then Remix will need to refresh in order to load the current account, which resets the UI. And I know that I could load the contract again by entering its address, but the problem is that his whole process takes a lot of time for Remix to load the new selected account.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the VM and oraclize...you just have to use the oraclize remix

https://dapps.oraclize.it/browser-solidity/

Enjoy!

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't answer my question directly. I want to know if it is possible to haveRemix display other available accounts besides the one currently selected.

Comment: You can if you use the javascript vm.  From your question it made it seem as if you couldn't use the jvm since you were using oraclize and this fixes that problem.